# Java Calendar pass by reference?

Tags: java, calendar

I have a class with a method I'm passing in several Calendar objects.  Within that method I'm adding several days/months to the Calendar objects.

However, on return of the method, the Calendar objects passed in no longer hold the updated dates from the method that did the 'processing'.

I'd have thought with Calendar objects, changes would be maintained regardless of where id changed state?  Code below:

```
Calendar aDate = Calendar.getInstance();
aDate.set(2016, 2, 30);

Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();

myClass.setStartAndEnd(aDate, start);
```

Then the setStartAndEnd method...

```
void setStartAndEnd(Calendar aDate, Calendar start) {

    if (aDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 1) {
        start = aDate;
    } else {
        start.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 5);
    }
}
```

In this case I'd expect 'start' to end up with 5 days added to March 30th, however on return of the method it still ends up as March 30th

Comment: references pass by their values

Comment: @AndrewTobilko a `Calendar` is (unfortunately) mutable, so calling `.add()` on `start` will indeed modify the underlying object. But otherwise, yes, Java is pass by value only.

Comment: @fge, OP changed only local variable (`start = aDate;`), not a passed object

Comment: @AndrewTobilko look at the other part of the branch

Answer (score 3):

You do two different things:

```
if (aDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 1) {
    start = aDate;
```

--by this, your reassign *local* `start` reference to `aDate`, so local `start` from now points not to `start` passed as an argument, but to `aDate`. Out of the method, `start` is not reassigned because reference to it was passed by value;

```
} else {
    start.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 5);
```

--by this, you modify local `start`, which still points to `start` passed as argument, so all changes are reflected in the object out of the method also.

To get rid of situations when arguments are reassigned by mistake, make them `final`:

```
void setStartAndEnd(final Calendar aDate, final Calendar start) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: A very good point about making arguments final. It is one of the thing we really drill into our interns. It eliminates a whole class of errors immediately.

Answer (score 1):

As @fge noted, the Calendar object is mutable. Therefore, when the `start` object is  passed to `setStartAndEnd`, method, it is possible to modify the object through methods such as `start.add()`. There are two ways, therefore, to potentially fix the code.

Option 1. In `setStartAndEnd` do not set the `start` variable (which is local) to end, but use methods to adjust its value.

```
void setStartAndEnd(Calendar aDate, Calendar start) {

if (aDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 1) {
    start.setTime(aDate.getTime());
} else {
    start.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 5);
}
```

}

Option 2. change the method to return a Calendar object and return a new Calendar object with the correct value.